# Assigning a color for each numbers in the set $A=\{1,2,\cdots,1394^{1394}\}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> We assigned a color for each number in the set
> $A=\{1,2,\cdots,1394^{1394}\}$. For the numbers $a,b,c$ we know that
> if  $a^2+bc-10$ be divisible to $15$, then the numbers $b$ and $c$
> have the same color. at most, how many different colors used in the
> set $A$ ?
>
> $1)2\qquad\qquad2)3\qquad\qquad3)4\qquad\qquad4)5\qquad\qquad5)\text{None}$

I started by writing $a^2+bc-10=15k$ hence, $a^2+bc=5(3k+2)$. from here I wanted to conclude that both numbers $a^2$ and $bc$ should have the factor of $5$, but I found a counter example $(2\times7)+6^2$, for that statement.

I don't know how to proceed from the equation I wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much of the problem statement is just smoke and mirrors.

Let's take $a=5$. Then *"$a^2+bc-10$ is divisible by 15"* translates to *"bc is divisible by 15"*. Just when is that true? Well, for example, it is true when $b=15$ and $c$ is any number. So 15 and any number have the same color. So all numbers have the same color.

How to deal with the apparent lack of this answer among the alternatives is up to you.

Comment: Perhaps "5)None" is a mistranslation? It doesn't make sense as it is.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin The question asked for most number of different colors not the least.

Comment: @Soheil Yeah, sure. What do you think is the most number of colors if any number must be colored the same as 15?

Comment: @Soheil: Ivan has given you both at the same time!

Comment: Yeah I think the correct answer is going to be "None".